# Как выполнить метод после запроса?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Добрый день.

Использую `Retrofit`. Есть метод который принимает параметры после запроса и сетит значения в UI.

Нужно добиться выполнения этого метода после выполнения запроса (двух запросов). Все четко работает если вызываю метод из такой конструкции

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getWinner(userScore1, userScore2);
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Однако если скорость интернета нестабильна то и ответ на запрос придет через другое время и метод выполниться приняв не верные параметры. Получается что статически указать задержку - не совсем верно.

Подскажите, как обойти возникшую проблему?

---

код с синхронными вложенными запросами

```
final Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            final GithubAPI service = client.create(GithubAPI.class);

            final Call<List<GithubUser>> call = service.getListOfUsers(new Random().nextInt(100));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubUser>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubUser>> call, Response<List<GithubUser>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        //get two random users
                        GithubUser user1 = response.body().get(new Random().nextInt(30));
                        GithubUser user2 = response.body().get(new Random().nextInt(30));


                        userLogin1 = user1.getLogin();
                        userLogin2 = user2.getLogin();

                        //1-й вложеннный синхронный запрос
                        Call<GithubUser> userFirst = service.getUser(userLogin1);

                        try {

                            GithubUser user1_1 = userFirst.execute().body();
                            //set values to TextView using user1_1
                            // меняем userScore1

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //2-й вложеннный синхронный запрос
                        Call<GithubUser> userSecond = service.getUser(userLogin2);
                        try {

                            GithubUser user2_2 = userSecond.execute().body();
                            //set values to TextView using user2_2
                            // меняем userScore2

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //метод который должен выполниться после двух вложенных запросов
                        getWinner(userScore1, userScore2);


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ooops, someting wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubUser>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ooops, someting wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу приме как это могло бы выглядеть использованием [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/tree/2.x).

Вначале определяем интерфейс с функциями для взаимодействия с API:

```
interface GithubAPI {
    //тут параметры для запроса
    Observable<List<GithubUser>> getListOfUsers(int count);
    //тут параметры для запроса
    Observable<GithubUser> getUser(String login);
}
```

И основной код по загрузке всех данных выглядел бы так:

```
//Создание инстанса retrofita как обычно
GithubAPI service = ...;
service
    .getListOfUsers(new Random().nextInt(100))    //загружаем список пользователей
    .flatMap(new Func1<List<GithubUser>, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(List<GithubUser> users) {
            // Т.к. дальше нам нужны только логины, 
            // то создадим Observable который излучает String

            return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<Emitter<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Emitter<String> loginEmitter) {
                    final Random random = new Random(users.size() - 1);
                    final GithubUser firstGithubUser = users.get(random.nextInt());
                    final GithubUser secondGithubUser = users.get(random.nextInt());
                    loginEmitter.onNext(firstGithubUser.getLogin());
                    loginEmitter.onNext(secondGithubUser.getLogin());
                    loginEmitter.onCompleted();
                }
            }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<GithubUser>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<GithubUser> call(String login) {
            // Загружаем пользователя по полученному логину
            return service.getUser(login);
        }
    })
    .toList() // скаладываем каждого пользователя в список
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // то что выше будет исполняться в computation thread pool
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // то что ниже будет выполняться в Android Main Thread
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<GithubUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<GithubUser> users) {
            // Если все прошло успешно и пользователе загружены, то обрабатываем результат
            getWinner(users);
        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            //Если во время работы произошла какая либо ошибка, то попадаем сюда
        }
    });
```

Если ещё подключить `Retrolambda` в проект, то можно привести этот код в ещё более читабельный вид. Так же, при желании, можно добиться параллельной загрузки информации по пользователям.

Answer (score 3):

> Получается что статически указать задержку - не совсем верно

Это неверно в принципе: а в друг во время запроса что-то пойдет не так и результат запроса Вы не получите?

При использовании асинхронных запросов, их результат возвращается в коллбэки. Собственно в них и можете разместить Вашу конструкцию.

Простой [пример](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests):

```
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
Call<List<Task>> call = taskService.getTasks();  
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // tasks available
            // здесь размещаете Вашу конструкцию
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
        // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: дело в том что у меня два запроса размещены в success() (onResponse) другого запроса.
Т.е в случае успешного "внешнего" запроса - в его onResponse() делается еще два "внутренних" запроса которые в случае успешного выполнения в своем onResponse делают изменения в UI. 
B И только после выполнения этих двух "внутренних" запросов мне нужно вызвать метод который принимает параметры. 
Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @FunnyBunny, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: попробовал. вылетает - NetworkOnMainThreadException(

Comment: @FunnyBunny, Покажите код.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: @FunnyBunny, Скорее всего в Вашем случае правильным решением будет использовать RxJava, но я в этом не силен. Погуглите по `retrofit chain calls`.

Comment: Хорошо. Благодарю за ответы)